# Is it possible to search for a Guid in a "Query By Example"?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, query-by-example

I need to find whether a computer with a given `Guid` exists inside a given OU.

To do this, I'd prefer to write a [Query By Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384378.aspx) that searches for a computer matching a `Guid`.  For example:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container);
ComputerPrincipal computer = new ComputerPrincipal(context);

computer.Guid = guidToMatch;

PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(computer);
// Get the computer if it exists...
```

Of course this doesn't work, because the `ComputerPrincipal.Guid` field is read-only.  Furthermore, the `ComputerPrincipal.AdvancedSearchFilter` does not contain a `Guid` field.

Is this possible, or is there some reason I wouldn't want to do this anyway (like a better alternative)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the way to handle this is to use [`FindByIdentity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348015.aspx):

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container);
ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, guidToMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to do a base search of the form . This will essentially allow you to search for the object by objectGUID and get back the match, be it a computer or some other type of object. You could then inspect the object and see if it is what you had in mind...